# Creating a new column based on existing column within table

Tags: sql-server

When you add a new column from an existing column - do you had to use add column or can you just drop it in?  My orig table dosn't have Previous Day or Next Day - those are the columns I'm adding. Should this work?

```
SELECT
ACCT_NUM,
PRODUCT,
Date_local,
CURRENTDAY,
LAG[CURRENTDAY,1,0] OVER(PARTITION BY ACCT_NUM ORDER BY Date_local DESC) AS PREVIOUSDAY,
LEAD[CURRENTDAY,1,0] OVER(PARTITION BY ACCT_NUM ORDER BY Date_local DESC) AS NEXTDAY,
FROM FINANCE.REVENUE03
```

Or I could alter table?

```
ALTER TABLE REVENUE03
ADD COLUMN PREVIOUSDAY=
    LAG[CURRENTDAY,1,0] OVER(PARTITION BY ACCT_NUM ORDER BY Date_local DESC);
ADD COLUMN NEXTDAY=
    LEAD[CURRENTDAY,1,0] OVER(PARTITION BY ACCT_NUM ORDER BY Date_local DESC)

END
```

Comment: This is not really a good thing to do, and Windows Functions can only appear in SELECT or ORDER BY clauses. I suggest you use a `VIEW` instead.

Comment: @Sami how about my edit using alter table - would that work?

Comment: im new!  I don't know what that means to me I'm just creating a column - that is how you create a column.  why would you need Order by?

Comment: Can't you just create a `VIEW` or even a `FUNCTION` instead of using a window function in a computed column which is not possible?

Comment: could you show me an example?  other questions I have asked have directed me to add things in this exact way so I'm failing to see why this wouldn't work here

Answer (score 1):

Simply, you can't use a window function there, instead create a **[`VIEW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** or try to create a **[`FUNCTION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** and use it with the computed column.

> Why?

Cause *Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.*

So, I sugget to create a `VIEW` like

```
CREATE VIEW YourViewName
AS
SELECT ACCT_NUM,
       PRODUCT,
       Date_local,
       CURRENTDAY,
       LAG[CURRENTDAY,1,0] OVER(PARTITION BY ACCT_NUM ORDER BY Date_local DESC) AS PREVIOUSDAY,
       LEAD[CURRENTDAY,1,0] OVER(PARTITION BY ACCT_NUM ORDER BY Date_local DESC) AS NEXTDAY,
FROM FINANCE.REVENUE03
GO
```

Comment: Thank you.  I've had other people on here say you can start with UPDATE TABLE OR ALTER TABLE - is that not the case? Do you have to create a new view like this with each change? You just select your table and can make updates - didn't think you had to create a new view

Comment: @newbie No, you cant use a window function there, and for the view, all what you need is to create it once and `SELECT` from it.

Comment: If there is already table 1, can't you select*table 1; alter table 1 ...etc.  Why do i have to create a view if the  table exists - i query it and then I alter it